# Spring Boot Starter Web Application crashes randomly

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hikaricp

Our web application is running on top of undertow server uses RDS Posgres (max connections 800+) for db and developed on top of Spring Boot (monolithic app).

**Technologies**
Springboot starter web
Springboot starter JPA
Docker container (sperate for BE and FE)
Hikari CP for Connection pool
Web server is Linux EC Instance with 16Gb of RAM and 4 vCPUs
RDS is 8Gb , 2 VCPUs

The issue is, the application hangs as soon as the usage increases. But both the memory and CPU utilization of both the VM and RDS instance are minimum (not even 50%)

When we tried to loadtest using Jmeter, the app crashes wherever it was given a load more than of 55 calls per seconds. Up-to 55 calls per minute is working fine.

How can we troubleshoot to get to the root case?

Comment: This is a question that is too broad for stackoverflow. The issue can be anywhere. Enable logging, get threaddumps, add a profiler to your application. But as a general rule of thumb it is doing the wrong things/naive things in your application. No proper tx management leading to resource leaking etc.

Answer (score 0):

The max thread count is JAVA was set to 60, hence breaking once hit the limit. Manually setting the thread count to a higher number solved the issue.